# How to setup IIS 8.5 FTP server to only listen to one IP address?

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-8.5

All the FTP sites I defined in IIS are bound to `192.16.9.3:21` & `192.16.9.3:990`, 
yet when I do a netstat the following is what I get:

```
C:\>netstat -a -n -o

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:21             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1168
  TCP    0.0.0.0:990            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1168
  TCP    [::]:21                [::]:0                 LISTENING       1168
  TCP    [::]:990               [::]:0                 LISTENING       1168

C:\>tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq 1168"

Image Name                     PID Services
========================= ======== ========================================
svchost.exe                   1168 ftpsvc
```

How do I force ftpsvc to listen only to `192.16.9.3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, there is a single IIS FTP process and it listens on all addresses on all assigned ports. This way it can then process the requests for various FTP sites on multiple addresses or ports.